# Identity regarding convexity of the logistic loss function

Tags: convex-analysis, machine-learning

I found the following identity regarding the logistic loss function in [these lecture notes](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~russell/classes/cs194/f11/lectures/CS194%20Fall%202011%20Lecture%2006.pdf) (slide 16) from Berkeley university:

$$\log(1 + e^{-z}) = \max_{0 \leq v \leq 1} -zv + v\log(v) + (1-v)\log(1-v)$$

But I could find neither proof nor attribution. Although the slides do not specify it, I am assuming that this is supposed to hold for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$. Does anyone know - if the identity does indeed hold - of a proof, or a reference to a proof?

For context, I am trying to prove that $\log(1 + e^{f(x)})$ is convex in $x$ when $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is convex but not differentiable in $x$ (i.e. I cannot apply arguments based on the Hessian), as part of a larger proof. This identity should make the proof simple by substituting $z$ for $-f(x)$, as it becomes a maximum of a sum of convex functions, but I have no idea where this result comes from.

More specifically, the function $f$ I'm interested in is a maximum of linear functions. Maybe there is a simpler proof I am missing, any feedback welcome :) .

Comment: Every convex function is the limit of convex differentiable functions: have you tried to use that?

Comment: No I haven't, and I will investigate that. Thank you for the insight. For more context, the particular function $f$ I am interested in is a maximum of linear functions, hence its convexity and non-differentiability. I will add this to main question :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every fixed $z$, the derivative with respect to $v$ of the function in the maximum is $$-z+\log\left(\frac{v}{1-v}\right),$$ hence the function is decreasing for $v\leqslant\nu(z)$ and increasing for $v\geqslant\nu(z)$, where $\nu(z)$ in $(0,1)$ is such that $$\frac{\nu(z)}{1-\nu(z)}=\mathrm e^z.$$ In particular, the maximum in the RHS is either the value of this function at $v=0$ or its value at $v=1$, that is, $$\max\{0,-z\},$$ and not the desired LHS. *However*, the exact same approach shows that
$$\log(1 + \mathrm e^{-z}) = \max_{0 \leqslant v \leqslant 1} -zv - v\log(v) - (1-v)\log(1-v).$$

Comment: I believe you made a slight mistake: the derivative is an increasing function of $v$, and so the function in the maximum is decreasing until $\nu(z)$ and increasing after it. Plotting the function for some values of $z$, it seems the maximum is $-z$ if $z$ is negative, and $0$ otherwise, which can probably be proven using limits of said function. Meaning, the RHS is equivalent to $\max(0,-z)$, which makes the identity clearly wrong for $z=0$, though it's a good approximation for large negative values of $z$. Thank you for your help, this eventually led to the answer :) .

Comment: Indeed there was a mistake in the statement of the exercise. For the correct statement, see the end of my answer.

Comment: I was indeed able to successfully apply your reasoning to show the correct statement, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the identity is wrong after all. Taking the case of $z=0$, $\log(1 + e^{0}) = \log(2) \approx 0.3$, and plotting the function $v \mapsto v\log(v) + (1-v) \log(1-v)$ between for $0 < v < 1$ makes it clear that its supremum is $0$ (as $v$ tends to either $0$ or $1$) and not $\log(2)$.

Plotting this function with a few different values of $z$, I conjecture that the RHS is equal to $\max(0, -z)$, which is a good approximation to the logistic loss for large negative values of $z$, so the identity still makes some sense. However, I am not sure it will help in proving the convexity of the function I'm interested in.

EDIT: As Did's answer pointed out, the identity holds if one changes the signs to:

$$\log(1 + e^{-z}) = \sup_{0 < v < 1} -zv -v\log(v) - (1-v)\log(1-v) $$

And it can be proven using the same reasoning. This allows me to prove the convexity of the function I am interested in :) .